# Assembly x86 - No success in loading address to register

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I am learning Assembly now, and I stumbled across a weird problem.

Take a look at this code:

```
DSEG SEGMENT
    STRING  DB "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog", 0
    NSTRING DW 45
    FIND    DB "over"      
DSEG ENDS

SSEG SEGMENT STACK
    DW 100H DUP(?)
SSEG ENDS

CSEG SEGMENT
    ASSUME CS:CSEG, DS:DSEG, SS:SSEG ; Assume
    MAIN PROC FAR                    ; Creating the main process.
        ; a bunch of code here...
        MOV BX, 0
        MOV SI, OFFSET STRING[BX]    ; Setting the SI to the string's current index.
        MOV DI, OFFSET FIND          ; Setting the DI to the start of find.
        ; just a bunch more here...
        RET
    MAIN END
CSEG ENDS
END MAIN
```

When I debug the program, SI is 0, and DI is SI+SIZE.
I know SI is 0, but it is 0 from DS, not from the memory!
Is there a way to get STRING's address with index BX?
I tried LEA, it has the same results!

I am trying to move into SI a pointer and into DI a pointer.
Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: There is no such thing as `OFFSET STRING[BX]` I am surprised that even assembles. `LEA SI, [STRING+BX]` should work, but of course with `BX=0` that **will** set `SI` to zero.

Comment: @Jester While using emu8086, this code assembles =)
It makes no sense, STRINGs offset can't be zero, can it?

Comment: It is zero. It's using real mode and it's at the start of the segment, so its offset is zero.

Comment: On top of what Jester has mentioned. Where do you set _DS_ (and _ES_) to point at the DSEG segment?

Comment: @Jester Perhaps the assembler assembles `mov si,offset string[bx]` to `lea si,string[bx]`?

Comment: @fuz emu8086 is retarded. It readily accepts the syntax, pretends that `[bx]` was not part of the `mov si,offset string[bx]` so it sees it as `mov si,offset string`. It generates the bytes 0xBE 0x00 0x00 which is `mov si, 0x0000` in this case

Comment: About segment registers... the `ASSUME` does not set them. Quite opposite, it tells the Assembler that you did set them to point to those values. But you didn't. (Well, the `cs` and `ss` are set properly by DOS, if this is .EXE, but `ds = es =` PSP segment ... in .COM `cs = ds = es = ss` and PSP is first 0x100 bytes. Or something like that, I may recall it wrongly from memory.